# Spring Error JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

Estoy realizando una aplicación usando spring-boot y ando tratando de conectame a la base de datos para ejecutar una query usando JdbcTemplate ya que la mayor parte de los procesos del negocio estan realizados el PL/SQL pero estoy presentando un problema al ejecutar la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from prueba", Integer.class);
```

Solo estoy haciendo un conteo simple para verificar mi conexion pero me da el siguiente error:

```
2020-05-23 02:39:06.430  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.servicios.SistemaWebApplication      : Starting SistemaWebApplication on Erick-PC with PID 17728 (D:\Programas y Aplicaciones\Informatica\Spring Eclipse\workspace\SistemaWeb\target\classes started by HardGamer in D:\Programas y Aplicaciones\Informatica\Spring Eclipse\workspace\SistemaWeb)
2020-05-23 02:39:06.445  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.servicios.SistemaWebApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-23 02:39:06.548  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-05-23 02:39:06.549  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-05-23 02:39:08.133  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-23 02:39:08.145  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-23 02:39:08.145  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-05-23 02:39:08.257  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-23 02:39:08.258  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1709 ms
2020-05-23 02:39:08.548  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-23 02:39:08.865  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-05-23 02:39:08.914  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-23 02:39:08.927  INFO 17728 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.servicios.SistemaWebApplication      : Started SistemaWebApplication in 2.993 seconds (JVM running for 4.246)
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sisweb.conexiones.Conexiones.count(Conexiones.java:11)
    at com.sisweb.servicios.SistemaWebApplication.lanzar(SistemaWebApplication.java:18)
    at com.sisweb.servicios.SistemaWebApplication.main(SistemaWebApplication.java:12)
    ... 5 more
```

Esta es mi clase de configuración:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ConfiguracionApp {

   @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
   private String url;
   @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
   private String username;
   @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
   private String password;
   @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
   private String driver;

   @Bean
   public DataSource getDataSource() {
      DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
      dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(driver);
      dataSourceBuilder.url(url);
      dataSourceBuilder.username(username);
      dataSourceBuilder.password(password);

      return dataSourceBuilder.build();
   }

   @Bean
   public JdbcTemplate getQaJdbcTemplate()  {
       DataSource ds = getDataSource();

       return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
   }
}
```

Esta es mi properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SFORM
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=aaa
```

Y desde aqui es donde lo llamo:

```
package com.sisweb.conexiones;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Conexiones {

   @Autowired
   JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   int cantidad;

   public int count() {
      cantidad = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from appfor.tbappfor;", Integer.class);

      return cantidad;
   }

}
```

Esta es mi clase SistemaWebApplication

```
package com.sisweb.servicios;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.sisweb.conexiones.Conexiones;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SistemaWebApplication implements ApplicationRunner{

   @Autowired
   Conexiones conexion;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(SistemaWebApplication.class, args);
   }


   public void run(ApplicationArguments arg0) throws Exception {
      int total = conexion.count();
      System.out.print("Aplicacion de Sistemas Web= " + total);
   }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar con alguna idea de porque me da este problema.

Gracias.

Comment: Hombre, te estás olvidando de inyectar el jdbcTemplate en tu clase Conexiones!
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

Comment: Puse la anotación @Autowired al JdbcTemplate  pero me da el mismo error.

Comment: Ah, veo que también te falta la anotación @Configuration en la clase ConfiguracionApp. Esta anotación indica a Spring que de allí puede tomar las definiciones de los beans.

Comment: Hola amigos, lo hice pero aun nada, me sigue saliendo el mismo problema.

Comment: Pues no sé, muestra tu clase SistemaWebApplication

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya agregue mi clase SistemaWebApplication .

Answer (score 0):

OK, el problema, además de las anotaciones que te faltaban, es que estas instanciando la clase Conexiones manualmente, entonces esta clase no queda bajo el control de Spring, y por lo tanto no puede inyectar el JdbcTemplate, por más que tenga la anotación @Autowired.
Para solucionarlo, agrega la anotación @Service a la clase Conexiones, y luego tu clase SistemaWebApplication debería quedar así:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SistemaWebApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

@Autowired
Conexion conexion;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(SistemaWebApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments arg0) throws Exception {
       int total = conexion.count();
       System.out.print("Aplicacion de Sistemas Web= " + total);
}
}
```

El método run de ApplicationRunner se ejecuta cuando tu applicación arranca, y está porque no puedes usar una variable de instancia (conexión) en un método estático.

Te recomiendo que leas más sobre Spring y Spring Boot, porque claramente no tienes los conceptos claros.

Comment: Lo hice me salio, lo siguiente:                                              .Description:

Field conexion in com.sisweb.servicios.SistemaWebApplication required a bean of type 'com.sisweb.conexiones.Conexiones' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sisweb.conexiones.Conexiones' in your configuration.

Comment: Perdón, tu clase se llama conexiones, entonces: @ Autowired
Conexiones conexion;
Y recordaste agregar la anotación @ Service a Conexiones?

Comment: Si, lo agregue; actualice el código fuente del post como lo tengo ahora en mi aplicación.

Comment: Mira, he copiado tus clases y me funciona perfectamente:
2020-05-26 23:54:45.792  INFO 4740 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-26 23:54:46.008  INFO 4740 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
Aplicacion de Sistemas Web= 10
2020-05-26 23:54:46.036  INFO 4740 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...

Ya má no puedo hacer...